# class path resource [de/ifd/remote/DatabaseService.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jar

I'm trying to run a program inside of an `.jar file`. To create the `.jar file` inside of te projects target folder I used the command `mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage`.

After I start the program with `java -jar middleware-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` an error message appears.

The entire error message:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)

08:33:38.573 [main] INFO  middleware.Main - Starting Main v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_192 on JPR-NB with PID 14832 (C:\Projekte\middleware\de.ifd.middleware-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\target\middleware-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by MFI in C:\Projekte\middleware\de.ifd.middleware-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\target)
08:33:38.583 [main] INFO  middleware.Main - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
08:33:39.489 [main] WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [middleware.Main]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [de/ifd/remote/DatabaseService.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
08:33:39.532 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [middleware.Main]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [de/ifd/remote/DatabaseService.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164)
        at middleware.Main.main(Main.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [de/ifd/remote/DatabaseService.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:199)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:55)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
        at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86)
        at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:696)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1024)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:386)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:332)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:304)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175)
        ... 20 common frames omitted
```

The resource the program was not able to find is located inside another project. I referenced the remote project inside the Java Build Path and inside my `pom.xml`.

Project dependency inside of `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>remote</groupId>
            <artifactId>remote</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:\Users\mfi\Downloads\LaunchableJar\remote.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

The `DatabaseService.class` is an interface which contains method I can call over network using JSON RPC.

The interface gets implemented only once inside my project. Inside the `DatabaseServiceImpl.class`:

```
package middleware;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.jdbc.ReturningWork;
import org.hibernate.jdbc.Work;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.spring.AutoJsonRpcServiceImpl;

import de.ifd.remote.ServiceInformation;
import de.ifd.remote.ServiceSystem;
import de.ifd.remote.UserSettings;

/**
 * Implementation of the ServiceInterface. This class gets called over JSON RPC
 * by the Service-Ticket-App.
 * 
 * @author MFI
 *
 */
@Service
@AutoJsonRpcServiceImpl()
public class DatabaseServiceImpl implements de.ifd.remote.DatabaseService {
    @Override
    public List<ServiceInformation> getServiceInformations() {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            ReturningWork<List<ServiceInformation>> returningWork = new ReturningWork<List<ServiceInformation>>() {
                @Override
                public List<ServiceInformation> execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                    List<ServiceInformation> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

                    // read data from database
                    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM BCSTASKS_SERVICE");

                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    // Cycle trough each result
                    while (rs.next()) {
                     // Create a new ServiceInformation with the name and description
                        ServiceInformation tempInformation = new ServiceInformation(rs.getString("NAME"),
                                rs.getString("ATTACHMENTCOMPONENT"), new ArrayList<>(),
                                rs.getBoolean("WASSHOWN"));
                        // Add the ServiceInformation to the list
                        returnList.add(tempInformation);
                    }

                    stmt.close();

                    return returnList;
                }
            };

            return session.doReturningWork(returningWork);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<ServiceInformation> getNewServiceInformations(List<ServiceSystem> userSystemList) {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            ReturningWork<List<ServiceInformation>> returningWork = new ReturningWork<List<ServiceInformation>>() {
                @Override
                public List<ServiceInformation> execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                    List<ServiceInformation> returnList = new LinkedList<>();

                    // Read data from database
                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM BCSTASKS_SERVICE");

                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    // Cycle trough each result
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        List<ServiceSystem> ticketSystemList = Database
                                .getSystemListFromTicket(rs.getString("IFD_PRODUKTBESTANDTEILE"));

                        for (int i = 0; i < ticketSystemList.size(); i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < userSystemList.size(); j++) {
                                if (ticketSystemList.get(i).getSystem() == userSystemList.get(j).getSystem()
                                        && rs.getString("STATE").toLowerCase().contains("neu")) {
                                    // Add new Service information to the list
                                    returnList.add(new ServiceInformation(rs.getString("NAME"),
                                            rs.getString("ATTACHMENTCOMPONENT"),
                                            Database.getSystemListFromTicket(rs.getString("IFD_PRODUKTBESTANDTEILE")),
                                            rs.getBoolean("WASSHOWN")));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    stmt.close();

                    return returnList;
                }
            };

            return session.doReturningWork(returningWork);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getServiceInformationsSize() {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            ReturningWork<Integer> returningWork = new ReturningWork<Integer>() {
                Integer size = 0;

                @Override
                public Integer execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                    // read data from database
                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DBO.BCSTASKS_SERVICE");

                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        // Ticket found in the database = +1 Size
                        size++;
                    }

                    stmt.close();

                    return size;
                }
            };

            return session.doReturningWork(returningWork);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setNewServiceInformationsToShown(List<ServiceInformation> newServiceInformationList) {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            session.doWork(new Work() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                    for (ServiceInformation serviceInfo : newServiceInformationList) {
                        // Sets all Service information with the Status Neu to Shown
                        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                                "UPDATE DBO.BCSTASKS_SERVICE SET WASSHOWN = 1 WHERE NAME = ? AND WASSHOWN = 0");
                        stmt.setString(1, serviceInfo.getTicketName());
                        stmt.executeUpdate();
                        stmt.close();
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public UserSettings getUserSettings(String SystemUser) {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            ReturningWork<UserSettings> returningWork = new ReturningWork<UserSettings>() {
                @Override
                public UserSettings execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                    // Read data from database
                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DBO.USER_PROPERTIES");

                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        // Search if the User exists in the database
                        if (rs.getString("SYSTEMUSER").equals(SystemUser)) {
                            // Users exists
                            return new UserSettings(SystemUser, true, rs.getBoolean("ALLOWNOTIFICATION"),
                                    getUserSystems(SystemUser));
                        }
                    }

                    stmt.close();

                    return new UserSettings(SystemUser, false, false, getUserSystems(SystemUser));
                }
            };

            return session.doReturningWork(returningWork);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public UserSettings createNewUser(String SystemUser) {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            ReturningWork<UserSettings> returningWork = new ReturningWork<UserSettings>() {

                @Override
                public UserSettings execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(
                            "INSERT INTO DBO.USER_PROPERTIES(systemUser, allowNotification) VALUES (?, 0);");
                    statement.setString(1, SystemUser);
                    statement.execute();
                    statement.close();

                    statement.close();

                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DBO.USER_PROPERTIES");

                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        if (rs.getString("systemUser").equals(SystemUser)) {
                            // Get the newly created User
                            return new UserSettings(SystemUser, true, rs.getBoolean("allowNotification"),
                                    getUserSystems(SystemUser));
                        }
                    }

                    stmt.close();

                    // If no User was found in the database create a new User
                    return new UserSettings(SystemUser, false, false, getUserSystems(SystemUser));
                }
            };

            return session.doReturningWork(returningWork);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void UpdateUserInformation(String SystemUser, Boolean allowNotifications, ServiceSystem serviceSystem) {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            session.doWork(new Work() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                    if (allowNotifications != null) {
                        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                                "UPDATE DBO.USER_PROPERTIES SET ALLOWNOTIFICATION = ? WHERE SYSTEMUSER = ? AND ALLOWNOTIFICATION = ?");
                        stmt.setBoolean(1, allowNotifications); // Value to set
                        stmt.setString(2, SystemUser);
                        stmt.setBoolean(3, !allowNotifications); // Current value
                        stmt.executeUpdate();
                        stmt.close();
                    }

                    if (serviceSystem != null) {
                        Database.UpdateSystemUserTable(SystemUser, serviceSystem);
                    }

                    // Add more customizable options
                }

            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<ServiceSystem> getUserSystems(String SystemUser) {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            ReturningWork<List<ServiceSystem>> returningWork = new ReturningWork<List<ServiceSystem>>() {
                @Override
                public List<ServiceSystem> execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                    List<ServiceSystem> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DBO.USER_SYSTEMS");

                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        if (rs.getString("SYSTEMUSER").equals(SystemUser)) {
                            returnList.add(new ServiceSystem(rs.getString("SYSTEMNAME"),
                                    Database.getCorrectSystem(rs.getString("SYSTEMNAME")), true));
                        }
                    }

                    return returnList;
                }
            };

            return session.doReturningWork(returningWork);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<ServiceInformation> getPersonalServiceInformations(List<ServiceSystem> userSystemList) {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            ReturningWork<List<ServiceInformation>> returningWork = new ReturningWork<List<ServiceInformation>>() {
                @Override
                public List<ServiceInformation> execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                    List<ServiceInformation> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

                    // read data from database
                    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM BCSTASKS_SERVICE");

                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    // Cycle trough each result
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        List<ServiceSystem> ticketSystemList = Database
                                .getSystemListFromTicket(rs.getString("IFD_PRODUKTBESTANDTEILE"));

                        for (int i = 0; i < ticketSystemList.size(); i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < userSystemList.size(); j++) {
                                if (ticketSystemList.get(i).getSystem() == userSystemList.get(j).getSystem()) {
                                    // Create a new ServiceInformation with the name and description
                                    ServiceInformation tempInformation = new ServiceInformation(rs.getString("NAME"),
                                            rs.getString("ATTACHMENTCOMPONENT"), ticketSystemList,
                                            rs.getBoolean("WASSHOWN"));
                                    // Add the ServiceInformation to the list
                                    returnList.add(tempInformation);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    stmt.close();

                    return returnList;
                }
            };

            return session.doReturningWork(returningWork);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside of my IDE (Eclipse) everything is working fine, but the `.jar file` throws the error above.

I know many other people have this problem, but most of them tried to load a file (.xml for example) and I'm trying to implement an interface. I don't know how much this is different.

I would really appreciate if you could help me out. Thanks in advance-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if your system scoped dependency is included in the jar! You can unpack the jar with any zip tool.

If you want to include it, check the includeSystemScope option of the spring-boot:repackage goal:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#includeSystemScope

Just an example, so you can see how to add the option. It's added in the pom.xml file of your project.

```xml
[...]
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>full.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
[...]
```

If you don't want to include it you have to add the jar to your classpath while executing the jar:

(Unix style)

```
java -cp "middleware-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:C:\Users\mfi\Downloads\LaunchableJar\remote.jar" -Dloader.main=<YOUR_MAINCLASS_HERE> org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really dumb question, but how do I add an parameter to the repackage command. I thought about this, but it doesn't work: `mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage includeSystemScope:true`